# Android Button With Different Backgrounds

Tags: android, button, vector

how could I get the button which looks like uploaded picture( [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoRd9.png) ) Here is whole button, inside him are vector icon(xml). Behind icon has to be different background color than color which are behind text

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" //Set Image here
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SomeText"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
```